# (laravel4) printing out posts with tags

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I'm trying to print my tags along with my posts (which are named tutorials).

```
class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $tutorials = Tutorial::where('draft', '=', 0)->get();
        $tags = $tutorials->first()->tags()->get();

        return View::make('home', array(
            'tags' => $tags,
            'tutorials' => $tutorials
        ));
    }
}
```

If I do this it works, but obviously I always just get the first tag there is, and not the tag that belongs to the tutorial. I've been trying to get it to work since yesterday but I'm just stuck once again...

Tutorial model:

```
class Tutorial extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'tutorials';

    public function tags() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tag', 'tutorials_tags', 'tutorial_id');
    }
}
```

Tag model:

```
class Tag extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'tags';

    public function tutorials() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Tutorial', 'tutorials_tags', 'tag_id');
    }
}
```

Home view:

```
@foreach($tutorials as $tutorial)

    <p>{{$tutorial->title}}</p>
    <p>{{$tutorial->body}}</p>

    @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <p><b>Tags:</b> {{$tag->name}}</p>
    @endforeach

    <br>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you also attach the code for the `home` view?

Comment: Hey you again^^ Home view is attached now. Thanks once again.

Comment: So you want to list all tutorials, along with the tags associated with each? Or you want to get the first tutorial only, with its tags?

Comment: I want to get all tutorials along with the associated tags.

Comment: I would suggest you edit the title to something like "How to output Eloquent models with their relationship?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You controller code is a bit ambiguous, I assume that you want to list all tutorials, along with tags associated with each tutorial.

You can utilize Laravel's eager loading for that, hint: `with('tags')`. Basically it will tell Laravel that, hey when you fetch the tutorials for me, bring them back "with their tags". So you don't need to fetch the tags separately like what you're trying to do.

So in your HomeController:

```
class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $tutorials = Tutorial::with('tags')->where('draft', '=', 0)->get();

        return View::make('home', array(
            'tutorials' => $tutorials
        ));
    }
}
```

And your view:

```
@foreach($tutorials as $tutorial)

    <p>{{$tutorial->title}}</p>
    <p>{{$tutorial->body}}</p>

    @foreach($tutorial->tags as $tag)
        <p><b>Tags:</b> {{$tag->name}}</p>
    @endforeach

    <br>

@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks! Once again helped me, you are my hero. Thanks alot

Comment: Next time I'll provide only hints! :p